# Best way to create a script using limited resources

Tags: .net, sql

I need to create a script using only the resource already installed on a pc (windows 7). I cannot install anything else (I.E software, drivers). The only other programs installed are .net framework (which I have no experience), and Microsoft server 2008 express (I have some SQL experience).

The script needs to accomplish the following.
    1.  Get information for a DB table
    2.  Format and email that information. The information format will always be the same and the email will never change.

Can this be accomplished with what I have available? If so what is the best language or combination of languages should I use?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307(v=sql.100).aspx

You can accomplish that with what you have, it appears. You may need some more practice Googling, though. =)